# CesiumJS: Calculate sloping angle of polygon

Tags: typescript, math, vector, 3d, cesiumjs

I have plotted a polygon in CesiumJS and now I need to retrieve the angle at which the polygon lies relative to the 3d place. Attached is an image of the polygon. How do I calculate this angle? I refer to it as the angle of inclination but I am not sure this is the correct term.

Research indicates that I need to calculate the normal vector of the panel using its vertices (points with x, y, z coordinates) and then determine the angle between this normal vector and the vertical. Is this the correct approach?  [plotted polygon image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFoeD.jpg)

I have tried to calculate the normal vector of the panel using its vertices (points with x, y, z coordinates) and then determine the angle between this normal vector and the vertical. A follow up question would be is the vertical vector in cesium JS at (0,0,1) in the coordinate system?

Comment: You can use the vector cross product to get the unit normal. e.g. If A,B, C are adjacent vertices, then Nhat = (A-B)x(C-B) / |(A-B)x(C-B)|. If Vhat is your 'vertical' unit vector, and theta is the angle between that and Nhat, then Nhat.Vhat = cos(theta).